# Basic Neural Network Input Format

Tags: neural-network, format, artificial-intelligence

What is the syntax for a neural network input?

I am new to this, so that may not even be the best way to ask the question. I've read a number of explanations of input/weight and how it works, but it's all sort of "word problems." I'll see an explanation like, "You're deciding to go to a concert or not. If the weather is good, x<sub>1</sub> = 1, and if the weather is bad, x<sub>1</sub> = 0. The weather is important to you, so we'll give it a weight w<sub>1</sub> = 6."

But how would you actually format that and feed it into the network as an input?

Would it be something like this?

var weather = [1,6];

Basically I'm just hoping someone can give me an example of how one would encode "The weather is good, and that is important to me" as an input.

(Full disclosure, I am not actually trying to code a neural network, this is just an example in an article I'm writing. However, I want the example to be expressed accurately.)